# WPF does not align path properly at run time

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend, controltemplate

I have a 16x16 vector drawn up in Expression Design that I imported in to Blend and used in a control template. Here's the XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CircularButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="Layer_1" Width="16" Height="16" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
        <Ellipse x:Name="_circle" Width="15.0208" Height="15.0208" Canvas.Left="0.375033" Canvas.Top="0.479169" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF666666" />
        <Path x:Name="_darkShadow" Width="14.727" Height="14.686" Canvas.Left="0.232" Canvas.Top="0.357" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="Black" Data="M 2.02083,8.03473L 13.7501,8.03473M 7.84484,2.14584L 7.84484,13.8333"/>
        <Path x:Name="_lightShadow" Width="14.727" Height="14.686" Canvas.Left="0.857" Canvas.Top="0.732" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFABABAB" Data="M 2.02083,8.03473L 13.7501,8.03473M 7.84484,2.14584L 7.84484,13.8333"/>
        <Path x:Name="_plus" Width="14.7292" Height="14.6875" Canvas.Left="0.520833" Canvas.Top="0.645836" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF" Data="M 2.02083,8.03473L 13.7501,8.03473M 7.84484,2.14584L 7.84484,13.8333"/>
    </Canvas>
```

While Blend and Exp Design shows image neatly, at run time, the + sign in the center does not align properly when applied to a button:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting UseLayoutRounding="True" on the Canvas.

Comment: That did it :) Going to mark this as the answer as it's less work for me to do to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to tweak that generated code it gave you to give more defined values. Try this.

```
<Canvas x:Name="Layer_1" Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Ellipse x:Name="_circle" Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF666666" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Path x:Name="_darkShadow" Width="16" Height="16" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Black" Data="M 2.02083,8.03473L 13.7501,8.03473M 7.84484,2.14584L 7.84484,13.8333" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="False" Canvas.Left="-0.5" Canvas.Top="-0.5"/>
        <Path x:Name="_lightShadow" Width="16" Height="16" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="#FFABABAB" Data="M 2.02083,8.03473L 13.7501,8.03473M 7.84484,2.14584L 7.84484,13.8333" Canvas.Left="-0.5" Canvas.Top="-0.5" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Path x:Name="_plus" Width="14" Height="14" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF" Data="M 2.02083,8.03473L 13.7501,8.03473M 7.84484,2.14584L 7.84484,13.8333" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Canvas>
```